# In Lua how do you import modules?

Tags: import, module, lua, declaration, require

Do you use

```
require "name"
```

or

```
local name = require "name"
```

Also, do you explicitly declare system modules as local variables? E.g.

```
local io = require "io"
```

Please explain your choice.

Programming in Lua 2ed says "if she prefers to use a shorter name for a module, she can set a local name for it" and nothing about `local m = require "mod"` being faster than `require "mod"`. If there's no difference I'd rather use the cleaner `require "mod"` declaration and wouldn't bother writing declarations for pre-loaded system modules.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Either of them works. Storing it in a local will not change the fact that the module may have registered global functions.

Comment: But will storing it in a local give you a meaningful speed advantage?

Comment: @Vitaly: It depends on what you're doing as to whether or not any speed advantage is meaningful. How often are you calling those functions per-frame? Is the code in question even a bottleneck?

Comment: I actually don't do anything in enterFrame event and use timer and transition APIs of Corona SDK, so there's likely no performance advantage in my case. Thanks for clarifying this.

Answer (score 14):

Some libraries work only one way, and some only work the other way

The `require "name"` syntax was the one introduced in lua 5.1; as a note; this call does not always return the module; but it was expected a global would be created with the name of the library (so, you now have a `_G.name` to use the library with). eg, earlier versions of gsl-if you did `local draw = require"draw"` the local `draw` would contain `true`; and shadow the global `draw` created by the library.

The behaviour above is encouraged by the `module` function ==> now relatively deprecated, any well written new code will not use it.

The `local name = require"name"` syntax became preferred recently (about 2008?); when it was decided that modules setting any globals for you was a bad thing.
As a point: all my libraries do not set globals, and just return a table of functions; or in some other cases, they return an function that works as an initialiser for the root object.

**tldr;** 
In new code, you should use the latter `local name = require"name"` syntax; it works in the vast majority of cases, but if you're working with some older modules, they may not support it, and you'll have to just use `require"module"`.

---

*To answer your added question*:
<s>do you require the system modules?: no; you just assume they are already required; but I do localise all functions I use (usually grouped into lines by the module they came from), including those from external libraries. This allows you to easily see which functions your code actually relies on; as well as removing all GETGLOBALs from your bytecode.</s>

Edit: localising functions is now discouraged. To find accidental globals use a linter like [luacheck](https://github.com/mpeterv/luacheck)

**Sample module in (my) preferred style**; will only work with the `local name = require"name"` syntax.

```
local my_lib = require"my_lib"

local function foo()
    print("foo")
end

local function bar()
    print("bar", my_lib.new())
end

return {
    foo = foo;
    bar = bar;
}
```

Comment: So do you suggest using the alternative proposed here: http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaModuleFunctionCritiqued

Comment: I suggest coding modules like: `local print,tblconcat = print,table.concat; local function foo () return tblconcat({1,2,3}) end; local function bar(...) print("bar",...) end; return { foo = foo; bar = bar }`

Answer (score 4):

I would say it mainly boils down to what you prefer, but there are some exceptions depending on what you are writing. Creating a local reference will gain you some speed, but in most cases this isn't a meaningful optimization to do. You should also point your local to the function you are using and not the module table.

If you are writing on a library then I would recommend creating local references for all the global variables you use. Even if you aren’t using the `module()` function, which changes the global scope for the code that follows. The reason for this is that it prevents your library from calling globals which have been altered after the library was loaded.

Doing `local io = require’io’` will ensure you that you get the table from `package.loaded.io`, even if _G.io has been replaced by another table. I generally don’t do this myself. I expect `io` to already be loaded and unmodified when I write Lua.

You also have to remember that there are several ways to write a Lua module. Some modules don't return their module table, while others don't create any global variable. The most common solution is to both create and return a global, but you can't always rely on this.